# How to change website addresses in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have spent all weekend to replicate my development server back at home. I have an Apache server with 3 IP based virtual hosts pointing to

```
1.2.3.4 /var/www/www.a.com
1.2.3.5 /var/www/www.b.com
1.2.3.6 /var/www/www.c.com
```

Now I have been able to set up a VM on my desktop, installed the OS, the applications, the db server, apache etc. Everything is looking good so far.

So right now I have,

```
192.168.0.111 at /var/www/www.a.com
192.168.0.112 at /var/www/www.b.com
192.168.0.113 at /var/www/www.c.com
```

So when I go to 192.168.0.111, I go to www.a.com so I guess apache is working aswell.

What I want to do is, instead of going to www.a.com I want to change it to another address such as a.me.add1

How can I do this? I am looking through the virtual hosts section, I have changed server name entry etc but its not working.

Can you tell me in big picture what I would need to do to set that up? My current set up doesnt really help me much once the site get the www address.

Sorry if I am not explaining it right. I can provide my conf files if you need them. I have webmin installed.

Or could you tell if Document Root of IP address 192.168.0.111 points to /var/www/www.a.com, will it always resolve into that webaddress. That is if I enter 192.168.0.111 the browser will redirect it to www.a.com. What effect does Server Name has in this regard then?

Comment: Have you restarted apache?

Comment: Yes. When I do enter my local IP, I go to the www.a.com I would like it to go to another address such as a.me.1 etc so that I am browsing local website. The actual site www.a.com is accessible from internet

Comment: Are you entering the URL by IP address or by hostname?  Do you have the IP address you entered mapped locally in /etc/hosts to www.a.com?

Comment: I am entering URL by IP. It gets resolved into hostname. No, I have not made any changes to /etc/hosts file.

Comment: How is your IP getting resolved into a hostname?  Your 192.168.0.111 address shouldn't be routeable to the Internet.  What do your Apache error logs from www.a.com and a.me.1 say?

Comment: I honestly dont know how the IP is getting resolved. I copied the /etc/apache2 /var/www files from original server and added them to test server locally. There arent any errors in the apache logs for www.a.com and there are no logs for a.me.1 etc since I havent "set" it up yet.

Comment: Is the www.a.com site that you are accessing on the Internet or is it on your local machine?  If it is on the Internet, check your /etc/hosts file for a mapping from 192.168.0.111 to www.a.com.  Post your apache conf so that we can get an idea of what you're setting up.

Answer (score 2):

Are you wanting the url in the client browser to change depending on the IP you type in? Or are you wanting a different site to load with a different IP?

If you want a IP or a domain name to go to a specific site use **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled**.
Add a file to this directory with the contents;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/whatever
        ServerName a.me.add1
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart apache (/etc/init.d/apache2 restart)

Make sure the domain name resolves to the correct IP address (edit your dns records)

If I understand you correctly this should do what you want...